# Converting check boxes to words

Tags: ms-access

I added check boxes to my MS Access form. Now I am trying to run a report based on those check boxes.
They are about 6 check boxes. How can I translate the check boxes from check marks to words?

An example of this would be on the form. Pizza toppings(onions,sausage,olives,cheese,chicken,mushrooms).
I need to be able to turn the check boxes from 6 individual check-boxes to make one toppings fields.

Also it is to late to change the table to use some form of list box.

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you trying to change them into words? You aren't storing the toppings as words in a database column, are you?

Comment: To put that in terms of data storage: text column of length 5: "B" + "A" + "C" + "O" + "N" = (5 * 256 bits ) = 1280 bits. Vs: HasBacon (bit) column = 1 bit. It's also a lot easier to write `WHERE HasBacon <> 0` than check for the existence of the substring `BACON`.

Comment: An even better idea is to use a [bitfield](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field) to store all of your topping into one 32-bit long integer field. Then you can just write all of the data out to a single number column (that'll allow for up to 32 toppings).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a new text field into your report with a control source similar to the following:

```
=iif([onions],"Onions ", "") & iif([sausage],"Sausage ") & iif([olives],"Olives ","")
```

And so on...

If you would like to have commas in between the ingredients, you could also use something like the following:

```
=Concat(", ", iif([onions],"Onions", ""), iif([sausage],"Sausage"), iif([olives],"Olives ",""))
```

And put a Concat() function similar to this in one of your Modules:

```
Public Function Concat(Delimiter As String, ParamArray Strings()) As String
    Dim s As Variant, ret As String

    ret = ""
    For Each s In Strings
        If Not IsNull(s) And Not IsEmpty(s) And s <> "" Then
            If ret = "" Then
                ret = s
            Else
                ret = ret & Delimiter & s
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Concat = ret
End Function
```

Comment: If this is a checkbox scenario rather than a radio button scenario, and they're talking about pizza, then this is definitely not a case where IIF() would be used.

Comment: Why not? A checkbox is nothing more than a boolean value. Maybe you don't want to nest the iif()-statements then, but it still would be valid to use iif().

Comment: Your edit is better.  I changed my vote.  Nice work!

Comment: Unable to use a radio button since I will be taking multiple entries.

Answer (score 1):

You want something like this:

```
If chkTopping1 = True then MyTopping1 = "Bacon"
If chkTopping2 = True then MyTopping2 = "Sausage" 
If chkTopping3 = True then MyTopping3 = "Pepperoni"
If chkTopping4 = True then MyTopping4 = "Mushrooms"
If chkTopping5 = True then MyTopping5 = "Meatballs"
If chkTopping6 = True then MyTopping6 = "Olives"


If Not IsNull(MyTopping1) then
AllToppings = MyTopping1 & ", "

If Not IsNull(MyTopping2) then
AllToppings = AllToppings & MyTopping2 & ", " 

If Not IsNull(MyTopping3) then
AllToppings = AllToppings & MyTopping3 & ", " 

If Not IsNull(MyTopping4) then
AllToppings = AllToppings & MyTopping4 & ", "

If Not IsNull(MyTopping5) then
AllToppings = AllToppings & MyTopping5 & ", "

If Not IsNull(MyTopping6) then
AllToppings = AllToppings & MyTopping6
```

AllToppings is now your text field.  I'm positive there's a more graceful way to do this, but my brain is kinda burnt after a long day at the office.